# How to scrape xml file using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to scrape an xml file from http://feeds.feedburner.com/Torrentfreak for its links and description.

I used this code :

```
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var document = webGet.Load("http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch");
    var TechCrunch = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//channel")
                                 from link in info.SelectNodes("//guid[@isPermaLink='false']")
                                 from content in info.SelectNodes("//description")
     select new
                                 {
                                     LinkURL = info.InnerText,
                                     Content = content.InnerText,

                                 };
lvLinks.DataSource = TechCrunch;
            lvLinks.DataBind();
```

I have used this in list view control to show on asp.net page.
using

```
<%# Eval("LinkURL") %>  -  <%# Eval("Text") %>
```

But its showing error

*Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source*

what's the problem ? And is it possible to scrape (fetch) xml nodes data using HtmlAgilityPack ?
Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: Why not use XML library instead of HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @jerjer : Actaully i am using HtmlAgilityPack to scap HTML data but when now i got encounter with XML file than i need to look out for a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RSS library instead of the HtmlAgilityPack:

Here are some links that might help you:

- http://www.rssdotnet.com/
- http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2010/2/8/simplified-c-atom-and-rss-feed-parser.html

Comment: what if instead of this i choose XML library suggested by jerjer ?

Comment: and is it more efficient than XML library ?

Comment: @CracLock, I haven't done benchmarks between HtmlAgilityPack and XML library, but i think there is not far difference in terms of effiency.  IMO, XML library is simplier to use than with HtmlAgilityPack when dealing with xml files.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the value is null. So there is too possibly's

```
select new
         {
                LinkURL = info.InnerText??string.Empty,
                Content = content.InnerText??string.Empty,

         };
```

or in the aspx. I think that it should be minus in the string like this:

```
<%# Eval("LinkURL")??string.Empty %>+"-"+<%# Eval("Text")??string.Empty %>
```