# htmlagility pack and System.xml

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a program that scrapes some data off the Internet using `HtmlAgilityPack`. Then it also uses the `HtmlAgilityPack` library to parse that data using *XPath*.

Well I found out that sometimes I need to use RSS Feeds and download XML instead of HTML. My partner and I used `System.xml` to parse it.

I find there is lots of duplication, and the only difference is that there is stuff like `XmlNode` instead of `HtmlNode`.

Is there a common interface or something I can use to clean up a bit?

Comment: Posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108644/how-to-scrap-xml-file-using-htmlagilitypack

Comment: Its not.I went to that exact question before i came here. The answer in the question is to use a RSS library instead of agility pack. More code is not the answer to trying to shrink my code.